# How to remember accordion state on submenu and remove on menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion menu and I want to remember the last state of the submenu so if a submenu is clicked (is active) the accordion remains open even when I refresh the page but If I click on the menu (not submenu) I want the accordion to remains closed.

```
$open.click(function(e, speed) {
    $("#menu ul ul").slideUp(speed);
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown(speed);
        $.cookie('active', this.id);
    }
});

$menu.click(function(){
    $("#menu ul ul").slideUp();
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stakkit/e86u5/)</kbd>

The problem is that the slidedown doesn't work correclty it opens and then closes immediately.
 
Thanks for help and sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0):

Yo!

You hava a double click there, it performs both of those functions. You click both the menu and the h3 elements. Therefore it performs the slideUp and slideDown. In addition, the variable speed is not defined, you can just add a millisecond amount to the slideUp and slideDown (api ref: https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

I suggest you remove this part

```
$menu.click(function(){
   $("#menu ul ul").slideUp();
});
```

Here's a forked jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/48LWE/1/ (edited: correct link...)